# как сделать таблицу на curses?

Tags: python, curses

я сделал набросал небольшую программу, и хочу чтоб данные отображались в виде таблицы вроди этой
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ну можно покрасивее конечно.
подскажите как это все сделать, или киньте ссылку на какой мануал пожалуйста, а то гуглится плохо

Answer (score 0):

Сдесь описание функций библиотеки `curses`: http://www.linuxlib.ru/manpages/CURSES.3.shtml

В общем вам нужно будет инициализировать цвета для шрифтов и фоноф (собственно и то и другое одно и тоже) и отформатировать вывод через `mvprintw`, ну а также построить рамку - для этого использовать `mvaddch` и символы псевдографики. Но, впринципе, ничего сложного.